# Connecting an Asus Viviobook x512Dto two monitors

Tags: asus

I have the ASUS Viviobook x512D laptop and I would like to and I would like to connect two monitors to it.

Which adapter will be best? Dual HDMI or USB-dual HDMI?

[image: Photo1]